# Completely, Utterly, or Tremendously excited?

Tags: adverbs

What intensifier would be good for "EXCITED"? And why?

I would also need an article or something to strengthen my knowledge of intensifiers, whether (and why) adjectives (or whatever) are gradable or ungradable. Thank you.

Comment: **So!**  *"I'm so excited, and I just can't hide it.  I'm about to lose control, and I think I like it."* -The Pointer Sisters

Comment: @BenjaminHarman you need to choose between UTTERLY, TREMENDOUSLY or COMPLETELY.

Answer (score 1):

Of those three my choice goes for ***tremendously excited***. Why? To be honest it is my gut feeling, and the [ngram shows it is by far the most popular choice of the three.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=utterly%20excited%2Ctremendously%20excited%2C%20completely%20excited&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cutterly%20excited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctremendously%20excited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompletely%20excited%3B%2Cc0) But now I’m going to engage in a bit of ex-post rationalization.

[***Utterly***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utterly) and ***completely*** are synonyms; *utterly* is more emphatic. So my feeling is *utter* and *complete* work best with things that can be, well, complete: *destruction, failure*; even *nonsense* can be complete if there isn’t a grain of sense in it. But it is difficult to think of a limit to excitement, so *utter* and *complete* don’t work so well with it.

On the other hand, [***tremendous*** is as per Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tremendous) *very large or great; very good or excellent*. This goes well with excitement, as it does with *popular* and *funny*, which are somehow related to *excitement*. In fact the above is the simple definition of *tremendous*. The full definition, sense 1, actually has something of *excitement* in it:

> **1 :** being such as may excite trembling or arouse dread, awe, or terror
>
> **2 a:** notable by reason of extreme size, power, greatness, or excellence < tremendous problems > < a writer of tremendous talent > —often used as a generalized term of approval < had a tremendous time >

Having made my case for *tremendously* over *utter* and *completely*, I’d like to suggest that *wildly* is even stronger than *tremendously* as an intensifier for *excited*. Picking up the Pointer Sisters’ line Benjamin Harman brought to our attention:

> "I'm so excited, and I just can't hide it. I'm about to lose control, and I think I like it."

If you say “I’m wildly excited” you don’t even need to explain you’re about to lose control: *wild* means out of control already. [This ngram shows that *wildly excited* is a more popular choice of words than *tremendously excited*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=utterly%20excited%2Ctremendously%20excited%2Ccompletely%20excited%2Cwildly%20excited&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cutterly%20excited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctremendously%20excited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompletely%20excited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwildly%20excited%3B%2Cc0)